# How to use the assembly System.web 4.0?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I get warring.

```
Warning 1 The referenced assembly "DudePro" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project. GroupInvater_vk
```

What should I do? I need System.web

EDIT:

I create .dll. IN dll i use System.web - there are no errors!

when I plug .dll into the project and do build .dll disappears and the more it VS does not see.

Comment: +1 For naming an assembly "DudePro"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your project is probably targeting the [.NET Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx), which doesn't include System.Web. You need to change your project to target the Full Profile, by using the Target Framework field on the Application tab of your project's properties.